# Console throws up "invalid hook call' and "can't read properties of null"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, antd, vite

I was trying to link ant design to my react file while I encountered errors. I used vite to download react.

My current files include:

index.html

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html lang="en">
  
   <head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8" />
     <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="/vite.svg" />
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
     <title>Vite + React</title>
   </head>
  
   <body>
     <div id="root"></div>
     <script type="module" src="/src/main.jsx"></script>
   </body>

 </html>
```

App.jsx

```
import './App.css'
import { Button, Space } from "antd";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>helo</h1>
      <Button type="primary">Primary Button</Button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App
```

Main.jsx

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client'
import App from './App'
import './index.css'

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
)
```

[This is the screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9sedF.png)

I tried using other alternatives to ant but still didn't work

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your screenshot, the error references `button.js`:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'usecontext")
  at object.useContext209 (react.development.js:1618:21)
  at InternalButton (button.js:70:13)
  ...
```

which a quick browse in the antd GitHub referenced this [issue](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/40600).

Digging on that suggests switching from `cjs` to `esm` [here](https://github.com/originjs/vite-plugin-federation/issues/173#issuecomment-1104635648).

This is not a complete resolution to your issue but will hopefully point you in a proper direction.